# Delphi: Making a component visible to live binding

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, livebindings

I have been trying to make a test object that has a string property visible to the visual binding form. The component is registered with the appropriate properties. Using XE8 and Firemonkey.

I can get it to show on the visual binder by selecting it using the hide show elements, however I cannot get it to bind the Foo string to a TEdit text property, the readonly (which does nothing yet) will bind to the Text Property.

- how do I get it show in it with default class visibility
- why doesn't the Foo string bind to the text property

The help files are a little thin on this. I guessing I'm missing something really simple here.

Object Code is below.

Thanks.

```
unit TestOBj;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.StrUtils, Data.Bind.Components;

Type

  TMyLBObject = Class (TComponent)
  private
    fFooString:String;
    FReadOnly: Boolean;
    procedure SetReadOnly(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetFooString(const Value: String);
  protected
    function CanObserve(const ID: Integer): Boolean; override;                       
    procedure ObserverAdded(const ID: Integer; const Observer: IObserver); override;
    procedure ObserverToggle(const AObserver: IObserver; const Value: Boolean);
  published
    property Foo:String read FFooString write SetFooString;
    property ReadOnly:Boolean read FReadOnly write SetReadOnly;
  End;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Test', [TMyLBObject]);
end;

{ TMyLBObject }

function TMyLBObject.CanObserve(const ID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if ID = TObserverMapping.EditLinkID then
    Result := True;
  if ID = TObserverMapping.ControlValueID then
    Result := True;
end;

procedure TMyLBObject.ObserverAdded(const ID: Integer;
  const Observer: IObserver);
begin
  if ID = TObserverMapping.EditLinkID then
    Observer.OnObserverToggle := ObserverToggle;
end;


procedure TMyLBObject.ObserverToggle(const AObserver: IObserver;
  const Value: Boolean);
var
  LEditLinkObserver: IEditLinkObserver;
  LSaveReadOnly: Boolean;
begin
  if Supports(AObserver, IEditLinkObserver, LEditLinkObserver) then
  begin
    if Value then
    begin
      LSaveReadOnly := ReadOnly;
      if LEditLinkObserver.IsReadOnly then
        ReadOnly := True;
      FReadOnly := LSaveReadOnly;
    end
    else
      if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) then
        ReadOnly := FReadOnly;
  end;
end;


procedure TMyLBObject.SetFooString(const Value: String);
begin
  FFooString := Value;
end;

procedure TMyLBObject.SetReadOnly(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FReadOnly := Value;
end;


initialization
  RegisterClass(TMyLBObject);
  RegisterObservableMember(TArray<TClass>.Create(TMyLBObject), 'Foo', 'FMX');
finalization
  UnRegisterObservableMember(TArray<TClass>.Create(TMyLBObject));
end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TMyLBObject` component does not have an `[ObservableMember('Foo')]` attribute.

```
type
  [ObservableMember('Foo')] // <-- add this
  TMyLBObject = Class (TComponent)
    ...
  published
    property Foo:String read FFooString write SetFooString;
    ...
  End;
```

See the example in the documentation:

[Tutorial: Creating LiveBindings-Enabled Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Tutorial:_Creating_LiveBindings-Enabled_Components).

Which includes this note:

> The ObservableMember attribute will be used by LiveBindings components to generate expressions. RegisterObserverableMember() will be used at design time to inform the LiveBindings Designer.

Comment: Thanks that's got the Foo property visible without having to go and tick the box. Now this is the one that really has me confused, Why can I not bind the Foo property to a TEdit text property. String <-> String seems the most logical thing.

Comment: What does your LiveBinding setup look like in your project?  Are you using the LiveBinding wizard, or a data source like `TPrototypeBindSource`, or what are you actually doing? Are you able to bind other component properties to the `TEdit.Text` property? I don't use LiveBindings or FireMonkey, so I don't know how well they work together.

Comment: Thanks for the help btw.
I'm using the livebinding wizard, its a simple form with a tedit and the TmyLBObj, Interestingly I can actually get the binding wizard to bind from the Tedit.text -> TmyLBObject.Foo, but not the other way. So the binding is unidirectional and only valid to the Foo Property, not from it. All getting to hard, maybe I should do the binding in code at runtime. this is an early foray into livebinding, moving from VCL to FMX!!

Comment: If you create a LiveBinding on the `TMyLBObject` component, you can link the `TEdit.Text` property to update the `TMyLBObject.Foo` property.  Have you created a LiveBinding on the `TEdit` component to link its `Text` property to be updated from `TLBObject.Foo`? Again, what are the EXACT steps you are taking to set up the LiveBinding in your app once the components are dropped on your Form?

Comment: In the livebinding designer, left click on the MyObj Foo property and drag to the Tedit Text property, it creates a uni directional link from text -> Foo. I need it to be bidirectional. Found an old blog by Damien Bootsma but it uses TBindScope (which is no longer a design time object).