# Custom component properties LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings

I've got problems with binding string properties to `TLabel`.

```
TGotManager = class(TComponent)
..
..
published
  property HotQ1: String read FHotQ1 write SetHotQ1;
  property HotQ2: string read FHotQ2 write SetHotQ2;
..
```

I did create a component because I don't want to use a TPrototypeDatasource.

My goal is to bind both properties to `TLabel.text` via the designer.

I did this with help from the answer here: [Delphi: Making a component visible to live binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963141/delphi-making-a-component-visible-to-live-binding?rq=1)

Example 1:

```
//with this only HotQ1 is bindable via the designer.
[ObservableMember('HotQ1')] 
TGotManager = class(TComponent)
```

Example 2:

```
//with this only HotQ2 is bindable via the designer.
[ObservableMember('HotQ1')] 
[ObservableMember('HotQ2')] 
TGotManager = class(TComponent)
```

The problem is that I only can bind one property via the designer. When dragging that property other ones which are compatible light up green.  When dragging the second property the other ones stay red.

Comment: "I succeeded with only one property"  Well, how does your lack of success with the other property manifest itself?

Comment: @martynA I will edit the question and explain

Comment: @martynA I hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

I don't get more then one property to work with visual Livebindings.  I do get it to work via:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/The_Entire_Project_and_Observing_the_Results

also for reference and automating things further this page from the Australian user group: http://www.adug.org.au/technical/vcl/using-livebindings-to-connect-the-ui-to-objects/

I don't accept this as an answer because this did not solve the problem. It provided a work around.